# Unable to modify config if Catalyst Session or Authentication plugins are enabled

Tags: perl, session, catalyst

If I enable Catalyst::Plugin::Session or Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication, I'm no longer able to add settings via myapp.conf, myapp_local.conf, or MyApp.pm. I've searched extensively and haven't been able to find any documentation of why this might be occurring. Is this a feature or a bug? I'm on the latest version of Catalyst and the Session plugins available via the FreeBSD ports tree. I tested this on Debian, and the same issue occurs.

```
p5-Catalyst-Runtime-5.90016
p5-Catalyst-Plugin-Session-0.35
p5-Catalyst-Plugin-Session-State-Cookie-0.17
p5-Catalyst-Plugin-Session-Store-FastMmap-0.16
```

I'm running the development server. The plugins are being loaded as follows in MyApp.pm:

```
use Catalyst qw/
    ConfigLoader
    Static::Simple
    Authorization::Roles
    Authentication
    Session
    Session::Store::FastMmap
    Session::State::Cookie
/;
```

Attempts to set config values fail as long as the Session or Auth plugins are enabled. The only exception to this is the 'name' variable.

```
__PACKAGE__->config(
    name => 'Will be accessible via "name"',
    foo => 'Will not be accessible via c.foo if plugins are loaded',
    disable_component_resolution_regex_fallback => 1,
    enable_catalyst_header => 1, # Send X-Catalyst header
);
```

I can see ConfigLoader and myapp.conf being loaded in the server debug output. Since this is a pretty basic setup that many users probably use, I'm assuming I'm missing something fairly obvious. Neither the plugin documentation nor any number of other sources I've looked up mention anything about this, unless I just completely missed it.

Update: I thought maybe the fact that I was running this via the develpment server might have been an issue. I made a deployment via Apache/FastCGI, but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I need 50 reputation to make a comment, so, I will question here,

Can you add this code right before your ***_*_PACKAGE_*_*->setup();** in App.pm ?

```
my $conf = __PACKAGE__->config;
use DDP; p $conf;
exit;
```

if you don't have Data::Printer, you can do:

```
my $conf = __PACKAGE__->config;
use Data::Dumper; print STDERR Dumper $conf;
exit;
```

this will show your current config.

I thing you are misunderstanding how it works. Since you say that "foo" 'Will not be accessible via c.foo if plugins are loaded', it should be accesible via $c->config->{foo} or c.config.foo if you are using Template::Toolkit

Comment: I knew it would turn out to be something simple, I forgot about c.config. What confused me was that it worked while the plugins were not loaded.